# SendMessage() to Spotify not working (C++)

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, spotify, handle

I want to send [WM_APPCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to Spotify using C++

My current code looks like that:

```
DWORD dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
HDESK hDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(dwThreadId);
EnumWindows((WNDENUMPROC)&WndEnumProc, 0);
```

There is also:

```
BOOL CALLBACK Remote::WndEnumProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    TCHAR className[MAX_PATH];
    GetClassName(hwnd, className, sizeof(className));
    string name = className;
    if (name.compare("SpotifyMainWindow") == 0) {
        cout << SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) << name << endl;
    }
    return TRUE; 
}
```

Header-File:

```
class Remote
{
public:
    static BOOL CALLBACK WndEnumProc(HWND, LPARAM);
};
```

The problem is that it returns **0SpotifyMainWindow**.
It prints 1 or 0 (return value of of SendMessage()) and the class of the handle. All in all it means that it tries to send the message to SpotifyMainWindow but is not able.

How to solve this?

Comment: It's not clear how your code fails. Taking it at face value, why don't you just write `name.compare("0SpotifyMainWindow")`? Please make it clear what the mode of failure is.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301371/sendmessage-always-returns-zero.

Comment: okay but what went wrong? is there need of an lparam parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WM_APPCOMMAND` message expects the "command" to be supplied in the high-order word of `lParam`, you need to do something like:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_APPCOMMAND, 0, MAKELPARAM(0,APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE));
```